# Creating a new column as a function of probabilities stored in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

Suppose I have a dataframe with a column **p** which represents the probability that an individual will choose option 1 as opposed to option 2.

```
id   p
A    0.2
C    0.4
B    0.7
E    0.2
D    0.9
```

I want to make a new column **choice** which captures each individual's choice, given their probability of selecting each choice.

Using random, I can do something like

```
df['choice'] = df['p'].apply(lambda p : random.choices(population=[1, 2], weights=[p, p-1], k=1)[0])
```

I am hoping to find something that is faster than this, and makes fewer calls to random.choices (I am simulating choices in the dataset many times). Does anyone know a method that could help here?

If it helps, the values of **p** are discrete, in that there are only so many options for **p** and many individuals will have the same value. I was thinking I could use some sort of groupby, but not sure exactly what it would look like.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Posting this as a comment because I don't know if it's the sort of thing you're looking for, but it would be simpler to generate a random number x from 0 - 1; if x < p, then 1 else 2.

Comment: @VincentRupp was just about to write the same, i would just create a dummy column with random values from 0-1 and compare both columns with .loc or something

Comment: If you are looking at simply generating *fewer* random numbers, then you can pre-generate a list of n of them and then go through it in order, where the next simulation picks up where the previous ended. It'll help to be sure n and the length of your DataFrame are relatively prime like 10 and 21 are. Or for each simulation, generate a random starting location for your list and then go in order.

Comment: if you are talking abut the vectorization of a large dataframe (as opposed to the random number generation), then this is probably the fastest method.